# Failed to link oracle/jms/AQjmsGenMessage_C

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-aq

I am attempting to link AQ and a JBOSS application using the Spring JDBC Extensions and Apache Camel. I think I have my Spring configuration correct, however when I run it using the `ojdbc6` and `aqapi` jar supplied with the oracleXE installation I get the following error

> JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aq' defined in class path resource [camel-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'connectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link oracle/jms/AQjmsGenMessage_C

If I swap the `ojdbc6` jar for `ojdbc14` I get further. However when the connection is unwrapped its not the correct version for the `getConnection` call. I suspect this is due to incompatible libraries, but proves I might be on the right lines.

We need to keep to the `jndi` datasource for 3 reasons

1. Passwords need to be obtained from a vault and this is easier
2. As the config shows we are doing additional processing in the same database on the same connection using hibernate so keeping the same data connection is essential
3. We need to scale so using `JBOSS` data source management seems a logical option.

Any ideas on this more than welcome.

Here is my `camel-context` and spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:orcl="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl/spring-data-orcl-1.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="aq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="connectionFactory" 
        use-local-data-source-transaction="true"
        native-jdbc-extractor="jbossNativeJdbcExtractor"
        data-source="jbossDataSource"  />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jbossDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jbossNativeJdbcExtractor" 
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.JBossNativeJdbcExtractor"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="jbossDataSource" jndi-name="cipDataSource"  />


  <camelContext trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="servlet:///in"/>
    <choice>
      <when>
        <header>name</header>
        <transform>
          <simple>Hello ${header.name} how are you?</simple>
        </transform>
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <transform>
          <constant>Add a name parameter to uri, eg ?name=foo</constant>
        </transform>
      </otherwise>
    </choice>
  </route>
  <route>
    <from uri="servlet:///tojms"/>
    <to pattern="InOnly" uri="aq:CIP.QSTART"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

**Additional info**
With tracing on for ojdbc14.jar I get

```
AQjmsDBConnMgr ctor (datasource):  enter
 AQjmsDBConnMgr.getConnection:  Creating from datasource
 Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
 Unwrapping JDBC Connection of type:org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6
 Using Closeable Proxy fo JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3ceb975]
 AQjmsDBConnMgr: constructor (datasource) org.springframework.data.jdbc.config.oracle.AqJmsFactoryBeanFactory$TransactionAwareDataSource@3da8acb9: 
Exception: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection
 oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection
```

There is no trace information for ojdbc6.jar as the application fails to start up.

**Edit2:**  I swapped back to ojdbc6.jar and noticed that the war file was missing this file in WEB-INF/lib folder. Added it back in properly and now have the same situation as with ojdbc14.jar.

I can run the tojms servlet but get the same issue extracting the connection via getConnection. Relevant section of the stacktrace seems to be

```
oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.getConnection(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:625)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsDBConnMgr.<init>(AQjmsDBConnMgr.java:399)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.<init>(AQjmsConnection.java:249)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(AQjmsConnectionFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:456)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:355)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:311)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:109)
```

Comment: when I swap to ojdbc14.jar I can run the tojms servlet but get `Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is oracle.jms.AQjmsException: Error creating the db_connection; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance`